# Browser Failed to load resource

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

I have my jquery datetimepicker api files Webcontent/js folder.I am referring to the resources like in the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery.datetimepicker.css"/>
```

But the browser fails to load those resources and moreover its showing the wrong file type in network tab like this.

```
jquery.datetimepicker.js   GET(canceled)    text/html

jquery.datetimepicker.css  GET(canceled)    text/html
```

Can someone tell me what went wrong here ? I am using spring mvc.

Comment: check path of js and css files.

Comment: Both the files are inside webcontent/js folder.. I tried moving it to the webcontent folder also but the result is same. Its not getting loaded.

Comment: Have you tried putting '/' before 'js/jquery.datetimepicker.js'?

Comment: ya. I tried that also but it didnt work.

Comment: Try using the full path (with http://) to determine the problem. It could be wrong MIME type or just bad routing.

Comment: what is your folder structure?